# Does ActiveXObject('Word.Application') work in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, ms-word, activexobject

I am going to write a program which creates and opens a Word Document from a Browser. I will be using JavaScript for this.

I need to know whether or not the `ActiveXObject('Word.Application');` JavaScript function will work in all Browsers, or only in IE.

Comment: ActiveXObject is only available in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1):

No, it is only compatible with Internet Explorer.

More information is available [here](http://www.ehow.co.uk/list_6702546_browsers-support-activex_.html).